# An array disappears in "for" expression,

Tags: javascript, arrays

There's some code, and it's not working.

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    var div = document.getElementById ('main');
    var img = div.children;
    var i = 1;
    //console.log(img[i]);
    for (var i=1; i != img.length; i++)
    {
        img[i].onclick = function () 
        {
            console.log(img[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Please, explain me Why is  img[i] in `console.log(img[i]);` undefined ?
How this bug can be fixed?

Comment: In computer programming, we start counting at zero (0).

Comment: ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: 1.) It is not a bug. 2.) Why do you start with `i=1`? 3.) Read about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: second of all, there's no point declaring var i before for loop.

Comment: What is `i` at the time it is undefined?  Also, it looks like you have a 1-indexed array, but JavaScript uses 0-indexed arrays, so you're missing your first element and trying to access `img[img.length]` which will definitely be undefined.

Comment: @AndréDion - In computer programming? So `window.onload = function()` is the zeroth line of the OP's code?

Comment: @Amberlamps - It _is_ a bug. OP's code has an error causing undesired behaviour, which is the very definition of [bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug).

Comment: closure and for loops... old news. Mark this as duplicate..

Comment: Funny how a lot of people got hung up on the `!=` thing and completely missed the closure.

Answer (score 1):

why `i!=img.length`?
Try change to:

```
for (var i=0; i < img.length; i++)
        {
            img[i].onclick = function () 
            {
                console.log(img[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This will only work when there is only one element in `img`.

Comment: When `i` increments by one and `img.length` is guaranteed to be an integer >= 0, `!=` will work just as well as `<`. Generally it's best to use `<` because it's more error-tolerant, but it doesn't make a difference in this particular case.

Comment: Did you test this? You're still going to get `undefined` logged when the user clicks...

Comment: is the element with id main doesn't have children, attribute .children will return an array with 0 elements so with length =0. for loop go from i =0 to 0 so it doesn't go inside

Comment: By the time the click handlers are executed `i` will be `img.length`, i.e., it will be past the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring var two times, remove **var 1 = 1;**

And assign **var i** value to **zero(0)**

```
    for (var i=0; i < img.length; i++)
    {
        img[i].onclick = function () 
        {
            console.log(img[i]);
        }
    }
```